# Installing Ubuntu 15.04 alongside Windows 7

Tags: dual-boot, windows

I'm unable to install Ubuntu 15.04 alongside Windows 7.

The installation is successful according to the installer.

After manual partitioning, the computer is just booting to Windows.

After choosing `Install Ubuntu alongside Windows` neither of the OSes was booting.

How to install Ubuntu alongside Windows?

Answer (score 1):

You might need to try booting manually into linux by opening the BIOS boot menu, probably F2 key right after startup (just press it repeatedly until you get that.  Use a different key if that's not it).  Once you're in linux, you will have to run

```
sudo update-grub
```

That should do it.  You may also have to change the default boot device to the partition containing the GRUB bootloader.

Answer (score 0):

**Loading Ubuntu on a different HD avoids the problem of having to choose between Windows and Ubuntu - instead you choose the startup device which appears to be far easier.**

FWIW I successfully installed Ubuntu 15.04 (from a CD burned with the 15.04 image) on a T520i with Windows 7 (professional) (64 bit - that may have made the difference).  **Also probably making a difference is I installed 15.04 on an external HD rather than the HD with the windows system**.

On the T520i   "control + F12"  is  what you hold down on startup to get the menu to select what device to boot from. (other computers will use different keys but there should be one to enable selection of booting device when starting up.   You may have to go thru several menus to get to the bootup device selection option.*1) Since the external HD does not contain windows, booting from it avoids any need to select between Windows and Ubuntu.  [[NOTE:   I tried installing with 14.04 (15 not then available) on an HP Pavillion 017DX and on startup I get the choice between windows and Ubuntu and select Ubuntu it says that a file is missing!  (which is why I tried from an external HD the second time)]]

AFAICS, the only downside to the approach of loading Ubuntu on a different HD from windows that if it's an external HD you have more to lug around.     I ran Ubuntu thru many paces for days with no problems with that setup.

---

*1   if you get the MAIN menu, use the arrow to select the STARTUP menu
on the STARTUP menu select the "UEFI/Legacy Boot Priority" option
which has the default setting [Legacy First]
change the setting to [UEFI FIRST]
then go to the RESTART menu (row at the top of the page) and select
"EXIT SAVING CHANGES"
It should then start up from the external HD in Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Wubi Method Of Installation for installing Ubuntu 15.04 alongside Windows 7. In this method:

1. Open the downloaded ISO file.
2. Run Wubi.exe.
3. Select the relevant options on the Ubuntu Installer Window that open.
4. Select "Reboot Now" and Click Finish.

For more details visit this [link](http://www.99computertips.com/2015/03/install-ubuntu-directly-from-windows-on.html).